# How to get actual character from unicode hex value

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have tried this but not sure if it's correct:

```
> parseInt('E01ED', 16).toString(10)
'917997'
> String.fromCharCode(917997)
'ǭ'
```

Doesn't look the same as [here](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e01ed/index.htm).

I got that hex value from here:

```
E01ED;VARIATION SELECTOR-254;Mn;0;NSM;;;;;N;;;;;
```

Another one might be:

```
005B;LEFT SQUARE BRACKET;Ps;0;ON;;;;;Y;OPENING SQUARE BRACKET;;;;
```

With:

```
> parseInt('005B', 16).toString(10)
'91'
> String.fromCharCode(91)
'['
```

That looks correct, so mainly double checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.fromCharCode` operates on UTF-16 code units, not codepoints – arguably a historical mistake. Use `String.fromCodePoint` instead:

```js
console.log(String.fromCharCode(0xe01ed));
console.log(String.fromCodePoint(0xe01ed));
```

If you need support for older environments, you’ll have to do the translation yourself (or use a package or something):

```
function fromCodePoint(codePoint) {
    if (codePoint < 0x10000) {
        return String.fromCharCode(codePoint);
    }

    codePoint -= 0x10000;

    var leadSurrogate = (codePoint >>> 10) + 0xd800;
    var trailSurrogate = (codePoint & 0x3ff) + 0xdc00;

    return String.fromCharCode(leadSurrogate, trailSurrogate);
}
```